# Lower indices height

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, subscripts

Adding a subscript to a dagged variable, the subscript is lower than when it is added to an undagged variable. Here's an example:

```
$c^{\dagger}_R c_R c^{\dagger}_R c_R c^{\dagger}_R c_R c^{\dagger}_R c_R $
```

I tried to solve the problem using `subdepth` package but it doesn't work.
I also tried an awkward solution with dummy upper indices:

```
$c^{\dagger}_R c^{}_R c^{\dagger}_R c^{}_R c^{\dagger}_R c^{}_R c^{\dagger}_R c^{}_R $
```

but still doesn't work.
I'd like to have all the "R" subscripts at the same height; possibly I'd like to lower the subscripts of the undagged variable at the height of the dagged ones.

Comment: `\newcommand{\pdg}{{\vphantom{\dagger}}}` and `c^\pdg_R` will ensure the same height of the subscript as in `c^{\dagger}_R`. But not if the subscript has no ascender (for instance `a`), in which case the superscript dagger will be lower.

Comment: `$c^{\dagger}_R c^{}_R$` doesn't work. The dummy index trick would work in the case of `$c'_R c_R$` but not in my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance you can use `\mathstrut` as a supplement for the missing `\dagger`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\leavevmode\rlap{$c_R c^{\dagger}_R c^{\mathstrut}_R$}%
{\color{black!20}\rule[-1ex]{4em}{.4pt}}

\leavevmode{\color{red}\rlap{$c^{\mathstrut}_R$}}$c^\dagger_R$

\leavevmode{\color{red}\rlap{$c^{}_R$}}$c^\dagger_R$
\end{document}
```

The horizontal rule in the output is just for reference in the first output.

The second output prints an overlay between the `\mathstrut` and `\dagger` superscript versions, while the third output overlays the `{}` and `\dagger` superscript versions (using [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)). The differences is more noticeable this way.

Comment: I obtain the same result with `$c_R c^{\dagger}_R c^{}_R$`, why is better to use `\mathstrut`?

Comment: This solution works fine but seems quite a workaround.
Still, if there's not a better solution I will happily accept this one.

Comment: @Red The result is (sligtly) different; try `\makebox[0pt][l]{$c^{}_R$}$c^\dagger_R$` and you'll see it.

Comment: @egreg I see.. very little difference, my eyes didn't catch it at first :-) Thanks

Comment: @Red The `\dagger` version is 0.18450pt deeper (0.065mm), indeed not easy to see.